# unable to scan WiFi SSID

Tags: networking, wifi, network-interface

I have successfully integrated the "SD-WLAN-SD-BT-8997-U16-MMC-W16.68.10.p162-16.26.10.p162-C4X16693_V4-MGPL" driver into Android 12 Linux 4.9.178 on our custom BG5CT-based platform. With this updated driver integrated into our image, we aimed to test Wi-Fi connections on specific channels using the country code=FR on the client side.
Here are the steps I followed:

1. I changed the module setting to loadable using "make menuconfig."

[image: Defconfig.png]

2. I added the module to the "atv_s_9344727/device/synaptics/sequoia/BoardConfig.mk" file.

[image: Boardconfig.png]

3. I also added the module to the script responsible for loading the modules.
   [image: detect_script.png]
4. Then, I triggered the build and flashed the image to the DUT.
5. Upon flashing the image, I verified that the inserted modules were present.

[image: lsmod.png]

6. Then, using the wpa_cli utility, I attempted to scan the SSID, but I could not initiate a scan.

[image: wpa_cli.png]

Here is the content of the wpa_supplicant.conf file.

[image: wpa_supplicant.png]

My question is: Is there a specific sequence to follow while inserting the module, or did we miss any steps during the module insertion process?

Best Regards,

Virti Choksi

Comment: https://w1.fi/wpa_supplicant/  . Is it running?